# Admin module is returning a '404 not found' after updating to Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, adminhtml

I updated to Magento 1.9.2.2 the other day and it has caused the admin section of a module I build to throw a 404.

Below is my admin section in config.xml file for the module.

```
<config>
-----------
<admin>
    <routers>
        <bannerslider>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Compnay_Bannerslider</module>
                <frontName>bannerslider</frontName>
            </args>
        </bannerslider>
    </routers>
</admin>
--------------
</config>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: [How to update Admin routers of custom module for patch SUPEE-6788](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88045/how-to-update-admin-routers-of-custom-module-for-patch-supee-6788)

Comment: Check this https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details

Comment: Hi @Muk, nice article from magento, but i have one question about, when i change in my config.xml as per article but still not getting solution, can i change admincontroller folder structure???

Comment: @dhrumin You should change the controller location as well as adminlayout file also. If you are using some where getUrl  there also you have to change. Or you update your question with module directory structure and controller file and adminlayout file as well as adminhtml.xml file for better reply.

Comment: @Muk Thank you, it's feasible solution for that, because i have used many of extension and get this error,any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Update: Extending the router configuration is the way to go:

```
<config>
    ...
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Limesharp_Playzone before="Mage_Adminhtml">Limesharp_Playzone_Adminhtml</Limesharp_Playzone>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    ...
</config>
```

Comment: Hi virendra, Thank you for the answer, but still not getting proper solution.